# fancybox 2 iframe dynamic width

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I've got a code:

```
$(".boxl").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                beforeShow : function(){
                   this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').height();
                   this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').width();
                  }
            });
```

The problem is that it sets the height and the width of first iframe ok, but for example if I click some url in iframe it doesn't resize..

Comment: why would it need to resize? the iframed page is longer or something?

Comment: I've got some links in my iframe and I want to resize size of the iframe by dimensions of those links